# How to define a Role without login page in TestCafe?

Tags: testing, automation, roles, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm having trouble to make my tests stable with this code.
Can someone give me some directions

My app doesn't have a login page, and users might get logged in different ways, what determines if they're clogged or not is an auth cookie.

So I decided to define a role by a direct API call to the authentication API then save a cookie with the user token:

```js
export const adminUser = Role('any-page', async t => {
  const loginRequest = await fetch(
    `https://my-auhtentication-api/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=${userName}&password=${password}`,
    {
      method: 'POST',
    }
  )
  const loginToken = await loginRequest.json()
  await ClientFunction(() => {
    document.cookie = `myAuthCookie=${loginToken.access_token}; Domain=.my-app-domain.com; Path=/`
  })
})
```

And then I use in my code test like this:

```js
fixture('[Admin User] Menu navigation')
  .beforeEach(async t => {
    await t
      .useRole(adminUser)
      .navigateTo(strictPage)
  })
```

The problem is that it **works fine** when I run only this test, but when I run it with the rest of my stack it becomes very unstable, sometimes works, sometimes not.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the ways, which the customers can use to log into your system?

Comment: Through navigation of a mobile app that sets the cookie for me or through a "parent" page that embeds my webapp in a iframe

Answer (score 3):

For end-to-end tests, it's better if your test environment is the same as your production environment. Your comment indicates that you use a parent web app to authenticate your users in the production environment, so the best way to test authentication is using the same parent app in your test environment.

Comment: I know, but my app is a microfront and will be embedded in multiple pages that I do not control, I just have an "api contract" to use the cookie for login

Comment: You could use a sample parent application, something lightweight, like a couple of inputs for credentials and iframe for your app.

Comment: They change the page time to time so it will break all my logged tests until I update the test. Not a good idea